# What game is this character with glowing energy from?

Tags: game-identification

What game are these screenshots from? It looks really fun but there wasn't any information on it.

[image: closeup of character with a ring of energy around them]
[image: character fighting enemies from a top-down perspective]

Comment: I'm not really sure, but it looks very much like [Path of Exile](https://www.pathofexile.com/)?

Comment: Path of Exile would be my first guess, but has been a while since i last played it so i can't say for sure

Comment: I think PoE would have given some reverse google search result with those images but it doesn't

Comment: It looks like he's wearing one of these: http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Chestplate

Answer (score 72, accepted):

That's Path of Exile. The first picture shows a Marauder. The second is a witch; he/she is fighting the last boss. The game is free to play and if you want to know more about it check out their homepage: [Path of Exile](https://www.pathofexile.com/)

Comment: As a extra, this game is available on Steam too.